# Rbenv: How to have two or more RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS when installing ruby?

Tags: rbenv

I want to install ruby with `jemalloc` without `rdoc` using the commands below but don't know how to combine them:

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-jemalloc--disable-install-doc rbenv install 2.6.5 -v
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--disable-install-doc rbenv install 2.6.5 -v
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set multiple options by using double quote.

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-jemalloc--disable-install-doc --disable-install-doc" rbenv install 2.6.5 -v
```